# Multiple actions for a single <form>

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I've a form "dataEmp" where user has to enter username and password and "submit".I have successfully sent the form data to "checkLogin.php" file but what if i want to send that same form to another file, "logout.php". After doing some searching i found I've to use jquery ajax to do so. I'm not very familiar with ajax so if you give the full code, it'll be appreciated.

```
<form id="dataEmp" name="dataEmp" action="checkLogin.php" method="post">
.
.  //user details
.
</form>
```

Comment: No, we're not going to provide you the full code, that's not the purpose of StackOverflow. If you want to use Ajax with jQuery, you can [read official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).

Comment: [jQuery.post() API Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) read once, if you have issue somewhere then post it as question, with the relevant code!

Comment: then just help me with the part where the form is sent to more than one file

Answer (score 0):

Here i am just giving your idea to make call with ajax on success page to where you wish to store data just call like below

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#loginform').submit(function(e) { // fetch data from form to submit to action.
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       url: '/class/check_login.php',
       data: $(this).serialize(),
       success: function(data)
       {
          if (data === 'Login') {
            window.location = '/user-success.php';
          }
          else {
            alert('Invalid Credentials');
          }
       }
   });
 });
});
```

but you should have to write you php code in your way to handle this request in server side.